# Error when writing to different SD - cards

Tags: android, sd-card, fileoutputstream

I'm writing a method to write files to any sd card on the device.

For example, I get 2 sd card paths for Samsung Galaxy S4 : /storage/emulated/0 is the path for an internal SD - card which is equal to `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()` and  /storage/extSdCard

here's the method to get a list of available SD - card - root  paths :

```
public static String[] getStorageDirectories()
{
    // Final set of paths
    final Set<String> rv = new HashSet<String>();
    // Primary physical SD-CARD (not emulated)
    final String rawExternalStorage = System.getenv("EXTERNAL_STORAGE");
    // All Secondary SD-CARDs (all exclude primary) separated by ":"
    final String rawSecondaryStoragesStr = System.getenv("SECONDARY_STORAGE");
    // Primary emulated SD-CARD
    final String rawEmulatedStorageTarget = System.getenv("EMULATED_STORAGE_TARGET");
    if(TextUtils.isEmpty(rawEmulatedStorageTarget))
    {
        // Device has physical external storage; use plain paths.
        if(TextUtils.isEmpty(rawExternalStorage))
        {
            // EXTERNAL_STORAGE undefined; falling back to default.
            rv.add("/storage/sdcard0");
        }
        else
        {
            rv.add(rawExternalStorage);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        // Device has emulated storage; external storage paths should have
        // userId burned into them.
        final String rawUserId;
        if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1)
        {
            rawUserId = "";
        }
        else
        {
            final String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath();
            final String[] folders = DIR_SEPORATOR.split(path);
            final String lastFolder = folders[folders.length - 1];
            boolean isDigit = false;
            try
            {
                Integer.valueOf(lastFolder);
                isDigit = true;
            }
            catch(NumberFormatException ignored)
            {
            }
            rawUserId = isDigit ? lastFolder : "";
        }
        // /storage/emulated/0[1,2,...]
        if(TextUtils.isEmpty(rawUserId))
        {
            rv.add(rawEmulatedStorageTarget);
        }
        else
        {
            rv.add(rawEmulatedStorageTarget + File.separator + rawUserId);
        }
    }
    // Add all secondary storages
    if(!TextUtils.isEmpty(rawSecondaryStoragesStr))
    {
        // All Secondary SD-CARDs splited into array
        final String[] rawSecondaryStorages = rawSecondaryStoragesStr.split(File.pathSeparator);
        Collections.addAll(rv, rawSecondaryStorages);
    }

    return rv.toArray(new String[rv.size()]);
}
```

So, this method return me in my case 2 paths : /storage/emulated/0 and /storage/extSdCard

Then I try to write this file :

```
public static boolean writeExternal(InputStream source, String filePath) {
    Log.d("MyLog", "dest="+filePath);
// собственно запись на флешку

File dest = new File(filePath);
FileOutputStream writer = null;
try {
if (!dest.exists()) {
    Log.d("MyLog","creates");
dest.getParentFile().mkdirs();
dest.createNewFile();
}

writer = new FileOutputStream(dest);
writeFromInputToOutput(source, writer);
Log.d("MyLog","writes a file "+filePath);
return true;
}
catch (IOException e) {
e.printStackTrace();
Log.d("MyLog","Error");
return false;
}
finally {
    Log.d("MyLog","file written");
close(writer);
}
}
```

now when I write the file to the first dir which is /storage/emulated/0 - the file creates fine.
But the second dir - /storage/extSdCard gives me back an error. 
here's my stacktrace and log with path to check it (it's the first line):

```
09-15 01:32:24.124: D/MyLog(26216): dest=/storage/extSdCard/Molitvoslovaudio/morning.mp3
09-15 01:32:24.124: D/MyLog(26216): creates
09-15 01:32:24.124: W/System.err(26216): java.io.IOException: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
09-15 01:32:24.139: W/System.err(26216):    at java.io.File.createNewFile(File.java:946)
09-15 01:32:24.139: W/System.err(26216):    at ru.eyescream.prayer.FileMgr.writeExternal(FileMgr.java:156)
09-15 01:32:24.139: W/System.err(26216):    at ru.eyescream.prayer.Downloader$Downloading.onPostExecute(Downloader.java:183)
09-15 01:32:24.139: W/System.err(26216):    at ru.eyescream.prayer.Downloader$Downloading.onPostExecute(Downloader.java:1)
09-15 01:32:24.139: W/System.err(26216):    at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:632)
09-15 01:32:24.139: W/System.err(26216):    at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:177)
09-15 01:32:24.139: W/System.err(26216):    at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:645)
09-15 01:32:24.139: W/System.err(26216):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
09-15 01:32:24.139: W/System.err(26216):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157)
09-15 01:32:24.139: W/System.err(26216):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5356)
09-15 01:32:24.139: W/System.err(26216):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-15 01:32:24.139: W/System.err(26216):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
09-15 01:32:24.139: W/System.err(26216):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1265)
09-15 01:32:24.139: W/System.err(26216):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1081)
09-15 01:32:24.139: W/System.err(26216):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
09-15 01:32:24.139: W/System.err(26216): Caused by: libcore.io.ErrnoException: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
09-15 01:32:24.139: W/System.err(26216):    at libcore.io.Posix.open(Native Method)
09-15 01:32:24.139: W/System.err(26216):    at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.open(BlockGuardOs.java:110)
09-15 01:32:24.139: W/System.err(26216):    at java.io.File.createNewFile(File.java:939)
09-15 01:32:24.139: W/System.err(26216):    ... 14 more
09-15 01:32:24.139: D/MyLog(26216): Error
```

What's wrong? and how can I fix it?

Comment: You know about this _Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()_ ?

Comment: I specified that I need to reach all of the SD cards  on the device. I've given a method to reach all of them. Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() returns only first SD card on a device

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What's wrong?

You appear to think that `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()` has something to do with an SD card. That method returns the root of [external storage](http://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/08/storage-situation-external-storage.html), which is not [removable storage](http://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/09/storage-situation-removable-storage.html) (and also is not [internal storage](http://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/07/storage-situation-internal-storage.html), from the standpoint of the SDK).

But, more importantly, the undocumented and unsupported means that <strike>script kiddies</strike> various people used to access removable storage -- such as what you are trying -- no longer works as of Android 4.4.

> I need to reach all of the SD cards on the device

That is no longer possible as of Android 4.4, and was never supported on any version of Android.

Comment: So , am I doomed to write to external storage no matter it could be as low as 2 GB and extSDcard or any removable SD-card which is a common case nowadays could be 32 gb and I can't work with it?

Comment: @user2976267: You are welcome to use Android 4.4's `getExternalFilesDirs()` method to get a spot on removable storage into which you can read and write. You cannot work with arbitrary locations on removable storage on Android 4.4.

Comment: Oh, great, so I can use this method I described in my question for pre-4.4 and getExternalFilesDirs() for 4.4 and above - is that right?

Comment: @user2976267: "I can use this method I described in my question for pre-4.4" -- I wouldn't.